# Proving an identity for the quantum angular momentum operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, quantum-mechanics, laplacian

I am trying to prove the following identity for the quantum angular momentum operator:

$$\vec L^2=-\hbar^2r^2(\hat r \times \boldsymbol{\nabla})\bullet (\hat r \times \boldsymbol{\nabla})=-\hbar^2r^2\left[\nabla^2-\dfrac{1}{r^2} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r})\right]$$

So basically I have to prove:

$$(\hat r \times \boldsymbol{\nabla})\bullet (\hat r \times \boldsymbol{\nabla})=\nabla^2-\dfrac{1}{r^2} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r})$$

I was trying to use vector identities like $A \times (B \times C)=(A \cdot C)B-(A\cdot B)C$ , $A\cdot(B\times C)=C\cdot(A\times B)$ or $A\times B=-B\times A$, but I am unsure if they hold when $\boldsymbol{\nabla}$ is one or more of the vectors. Any help please?

Comment: If you're ever unsure whether identities work with del, do a first-principles proof.

Comment: @J.G What do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll work in Cartesian coordinates, summing repeated indices. If $f$ is a scalar function,$$\partial_k(\tfrac{x_l}{r})=\tfrac{r^2\delta_{kl}-x_kx_l}{r^3}\implies\partial_k(\tfrac{x_l}{r}\partial_mf)=\tfrac{(r^2\delta_{kl}-x_kx_l)\partial_mf+r^2x_l\partial_k\partial_mf}{r^3}.$$Hence$$\begin{align}[(\hat{r}\times\nabla)f]_i&=\epsilon_{ilm}\tfrac{x_l}{r}\partial_mf,\\(\hat{r}\times\nabla)\cdot(\hat{r}\times\nabla)f&=\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ilm}\tfrac{x_j}{r}\partial_k(\tfrac{x_l}{r}\partial_mf)\\&=(\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl})\tfrac{x_j(r^2\delta_{kl}-x_kx_l)\partial_mf+r^2x_jx_l\partial_k\partial_mf}{r^4}\\&=\nabla^2f-\tfrac{2(x\cdot\nabla)f+x_jx_k\partial_j\partial_kf}{r^2}.\end{align}$$Since $\partial_r=\tfrac{x_i}{r}\partial_i$,$$\tfrac{1}{r^2}\partial_r(r^2\partial_rf)=\tfrac{x_i}{r^3}\partial_i(x_jr\partial_jf)=\tfrac{x_i}{r^3}(r\partial_i+\tfrac{x_ix_j}{r}\partial_j+x_jr\partial_i\partial_j)=\tfrac{2(x\cdot\nabla)f+x_ix_j\partial_i\partial_jf}{r^2},$$so $(\hat{r}\times\nabla)\cdot(\hat{r}\times\nabla)f=\nabla^2f-\tfrac{1}{r^2}\partial_r(r^2\partial_rf)$ as claimed.

Comment: I am not sure how you got $\nabla^2f-\tfrac{2(x\cdot\nabla)f+x_jx_k\partial_j\partial_kf}{r^2} $ from the previous line, could you elaborate?

Comment: I think I got it, I just have a doubt about the laplacian part, the terms that yields the Laplacian should be: $r^2\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}x_jx_k\partial_k\partial_mf=r^2x_l^2\partial_k^2f$ which should reduce (but I don't see repeated indices ) to $r^4\nabla^2f$ , unless I do this: $r^2x_lx_l\partial_k \partial_kf=r^2(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)(\partial_1 \partial_1+\partial_2 \partial_2+\partial_3 \partial_3)f$. but I am not very sure. What is the laplacian in index notation?

Comment: Something else there is one term $-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl}\delta_{kl}\partial_m f r^2$. Should I just get rid of one $\delta_{kl}$ and write: $-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl}\delta_{kl}\partial_m f r^2=-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl}\partial_m f r^2$ ?

Comment: In other words if $\delta_{kl}\delta_{kl}=\delta_{kl}$ or I am supposed to do repeated summation anyway despite the symbol being identical, that is: $\delta_{kl}\delta_{kl}=\delta_{11}\delta_{11}+\delta_{22}\delta_{22}+\delta_{33}\delta_{33}$. In cases when the delta does no show up with the same indices I  used to get rid of it by replacing one of its indices by the other, that is $\delta_{ij} x_i$ I would let i get the only non-zero-contribution value$ j$ so that $\delta_{j} x_i=x_j$. But doing that in $\delta_{kl}\delta_{kl}$ would yield $\delta_{kk}\delta_{kk}=1 $.

Comment: I meant $\delta_{ij}x_i=x_j$

Comment: @mathlover You're right, $\nabla^2=\partial_k\partial_k$. Meanwhile,$$\partial_{kl}\partial_{kl}=\sum_{kl}\partial_{kl}\partial_{kl}=\sum_k1=3.$$This is just a contraction of $\partial_{kl}\partial_{km}=\partial_{lm}$, which in turn is a special case of $X_{kl}\partial_{km}=X_{lm}$.